# finding basis of 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

for (a), I got

```
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 1

0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0

0 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0

0 1 0
1 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0

0 0 -1
0 0 0
1 0 0

0 1 0
-1 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 1
0 -1 0
```

Could you please check if this is correct?

I have no idea how to approach (b). Could you give me a hint?

Thanks,

Comment: For (a), you need to show that the set spans $V$.

Comment: for (b), pick matrices at random, it'll work with probability 1 !

Answer (score 1):

For (b), use the standard basis (i.e. zeros everywhere and only a one in the i,j position) but add the identity matrix to all of them. This will give you invertible matrices (determinants are 1 or 2)and they form a basis.

Comment: I prefer the probabilistic solution, it'll take the teacher by surprise ;)

Comment: You could get surprised back when the teacher doesn't give you the marks you were expecting.

Comment: Of course you have to give a proof that it works, I'll put an alternate answer.

Answer (score 0):

for (b), if you want to surprise your teacher with an unexpected (but rigorous) alternative solution, you can show that any random matrices work:

Pick 9 matrices with random coefficients in $[0,1]$ (with uniform probability for each coefficient), we can show this form a base.

First of all, being inversible is having a non-zero determinant. We want to show that $\det^{-1}(\{0\})$ has null measure in $M_{3,3}(\mathbb R)$, whose measure is the euclidean measure on $\mathbb R^9$.
This is true because $\det$ is a polynomial, so the set of roots has measure $0$.

Therefore you have probability $0$ to pick a matrice with determinant zero, hence all your random matrices are inversible.

Secondly, you want to show that this is a base.
Call $M_1,M_2,...,M_9$ your $9$ matrices, you just want to show that they are independant.

It is not hard to show that the measure of a sub-vectorial space is always $0$, therefore $span(M_1)$ has measure $0$ and $M_2$ has probability $0$ to be in it. Same goes for $span(M_1,M_2)$ so $M_3$ is not in it, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

To verify your answer to the first part indeed is a basis, we need to show the matrices are linearly independent (since this proves the matrices span a $9$-dimensional subspace of $M_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$, which is itself $9$-dimensional).  If we write them as the rows of a $9 \times 9$ matrix, and compute its determinant, we find:
$$\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 
0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 
0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}=-8 \neq 0$$
so they're linearly independent.